# SQLServer 2008 FailOver and Load Balancing

Tags: sql-server-2008, load-balancing, cluster, failover

I have a project with a 2TB database ( 450.000.000 rows). I need to provide to the project a solution that gives FailOver and load Balacing, what do you recommend? We are going to use a NetApp Filer for the Data Files and for the File System of the Project.

I read that SQL Clustering does not provide load balacing. If I cannnot have this feature and I have to go only to the FailOver what Server ( I presume that the key feature here is memory) would you recomend. We are adding 1.000.000 rows a day. Once the rows is inserted we are doing a lot of updates to that row for about 1 week then the row get static. Because of this I am thinking in some kind of history table or database or something like that.

I am open to the Os servers implementation, I was thinking of a windows 2008 server with cluster but this depend of the database solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that Failover Clustering does not provide load balancing. However, you can use some other technologies within SQL Server to spread the load, here are a few solutions for you to look at.

- Use SQL Server Replication to replication to other nodes in the cluster. You can use merge replication to have servers connect to either database and then have the changes in both databases be marged back and forth.
- Use SQL Server Mirroring to have a mirrored database on another node in the cluster. You can use the mirror for reporting purposes to spread the load.
- You can use distributed partitioned views to spread the load as well across multiple servers in a cluster.